# 'Class 'Facebook\Facebook' not found" Facebook SDK error

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Well I am new to facebook sdk. I have being following the guideline and performing the steps as written.. but I am getting this error and I dont know why?

```
 Fatal error: Class 'Facebook\Facebook' not found in C:\wamp\www\index.php on line 134
```

The error line code is:

```
<?php 
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '{app-id}',
  'app_secret' => '{app-secret}',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
  ]);
?>
```

This is not something I have made up, this is exactly the same code mentioned in facebook guideline! What should I do?

Comment: did you included facebook.php file?

Comment: nopes! include it where?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need to include the `autoloader` first to get access to the service methods and classes (as said in the PHP SDK Documentation for `Facebook` API. You are trying to use a namespaced class `Facebook\Facebook`, to use its methods, but you don't have the class in the PHP file.

```
require_once 'src/Facebook/autoload.php';
//Create the Facebook service
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook ([
    'app_id' => '-----------------',
    'app_secret' => '--------------------',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.4'
    ]);
```

Somewhere in your directory (if you installed the Facebook PHP SDK) correctly, you will find the `autoload.php` file which automatically `requires` .php files that you need to use the services and methods.

Comment: Yes as mentioned on the site, I have already added it!
`<?php require_once __DIR__ . '/facebook-sdk-v5/autoload.php';?>`

Comment: Is your autoload not including the file correctly? Try error logging it, and did you ensure you got all the right files from the SDK?

Comment: Well Thanks! The files are correct just the require wasn't placed in its correct position! silly mistake! but thanks anyways! :)

Comment: The problem, glad I could help!

Comment: Everyone keeps saying to just include autoload, but for me it's not working even then. Seems like Facebook just made the whole thing a lot more complicated...

Comment: Well, from my experience, It might be because you are using the wrong path separator like "/" instead of "\"

Answer (score 7):

I think you need to first import that php class into your current file

Put this line at the top

```
use Facebook\Facebook;
```

Comment: This worked for me by doing `require 'vendor/autoload.php';`

Answer (score 2):

Download the zip file from here : https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk/archive/5.4.zip

Steps :

1. Unzip the content (by either just double clicking on the zipped file or use any available unzipping software to unzip or decompress the downloaded file)
2. Navigate to the "src" folder.
3. Copy or cut the "src" folder and paste right within the folder from which you have your php files.
4. make sure you have created "includes.php" file within your php project workspace ie. the folder in which your web page is sitting.
   And add this line to your "includes.php" file :

   require_once 'src/Facebook/autoload.php';
5. Now in your php file(s) that has to do with facebook you can then add :

   require_once("includes.php");
6. Now save your file and go into your browser and refresh.

//Do remember to keep your work organised by now referencing all files that may be needed in your project via "includes.php". This may vary for some developers, depending on how and what you are working on.