# Facebook SDK Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException' with message 'Require

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

At first my code was like this without use namespace but as per the documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted

```
    session_start();
    define('FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR', __DIR__ . '/Facebook/');
    require_once __DIR__ . '/Facebook/autoload.php';



    $fb= new Facebook/Facebook([
    'app_id'                => '******',
    'app_secret'            => '********************',
    'default_graph_version' =>'v2.5'
    ]);

    $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
    //$permissions = ['email','id', 'first_name', 'last_name'];
    $loginUrl = $fb->getLoginUrl('index.php');
    echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>';
```

but it throwed the following error

> Fatal error: Class 'Facebook' not found in
>   E:\wamp\www\sugumar\facebooklogin\index.php on line 9 Call Stack

So searched online and found the following link
['Class 'Facebook\Facebook' not found" Facebook SDK error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32366714/class-facebook-facebook-not-found-facebook-sdk-error)

Which told me include the sdk file and use namespace, since I already included the sdk files, I put use Facebook\Facebook;  at the top

so my code becomes

```
    use Facebook\Facebook; 
    session_start();
    define('FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR', __DIR__ . '/Facebook/');
    require_once __DIR__ . '/Facebook/autoload.php';



    $fb= new Facebook/Facebook([
    'app_id'                => '********',
    'app_secret'            => '********************',
    'default_graph_version' =>'v2.5'
    ]);

    $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
    //$permissions = ['email','id', 'first_name', 'last_name'];
    $loginUrl = $fb->getLoginUrl('index.php');
    echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>';
```

But now it throws a different error, my appid and secret are correct... I am just trying to change from version 4 to version 5.

The error is

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException' with message 'Required
>   "app_id" key not supplied in config and could not find fallback
>   environment variable "FACEBOOK_APP_ID"' in
>   E:\wamp\www\sugumar\facebooklogin\Facebook\Facebook.php on line 133
>
> ( ! ) Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException: Required "app_id" key
>   not supplied in config and could not find fallback environment
>   variable "FACEBOOK_APP_ID" in
>   E:\wamp\www\sugumar\facebooklogin\Facebook\Facebook.php on line 133

Comment: `use Facebook\Facebook`, `$fb= new Facebook/Facebook([` - see any significant difference here? Forward and backward slash are not arbitrarily interchangeable  ...

Comment: @CBroe thanks  bro it worked, I removed the use namespace and changed $fb= new Facebook/Facebook([  to  $fb= new Facebook\Facebook(  .. I am using windows...

Comment: @CBroe if you post it as an answer will be usefull for other people...